# Ubuntu 20.04 LTS unreachable, although it is connected to network

Tags: networking, server

Excuse my basic question, I have installed Ubuntu Server 20.04 LTS on an old laptop to use it as a home-server for testing and other learning stuff. It was working fine, except few days ago it started going down, although I can see it connected on the router configuration and I can ping it from the router, however, when I try to ping it from my PC, it does not response. This happens occasionally and it comes back online after sometime.

some information that might help to provide support.

Ping from router:

```
no source interface or ip specified, using default route
PING 192.168.1.24 (192.168.1.24): 64 data bytes
72 bytes from 192.168.1.24: seq=0 ttl=64 time=5.636 ms
72 bytes from 192.168.1.24: seq=1 ttl=64 time=4.070 ms
72 bytes from 192.168.1.24: seq=2 ttl=64 time=10.023 ms
72 bytes from 192.168.1.24: seq=3 ttl=64 time=4.129 ms

--- 192.168.1.24 ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 4 packets received, 0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max = 4.070/5.964/10.023 ms
```

Ping from PC:

```
PING 192.168.1.24 (192.168.1.24): 56 data bytes
Request timeout for icmp_seq 0
ping: sendto: No route to host
Request timeout for icmp_seq 1
ping: sendto: Host is down
Request timeout for icmp_seq 2
ping: sendto: Host is down
Request timeout for icmp_seq 3
ping: sendto: Host is down
Request timeout for icmp_seq 4
ping: sendto: Host is down
Request timeout for icmp_seq 5
ping: sendto: Host is down
Request timeout for icmp_seq 6
^C
--- 192.168.1.24 ping statistics ---
8 packets transmitted, 0 packets received, 100.0% packet loss

=======================================================
```

cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml

```
# This is the network config written by 'subiquity'
network:
  ethernets:
    enp0s25:
      dhcp4: true
  version: 2
  wifis:
        wlo1:
            optional: true
            access-points:
                "SSIDName":
                    password: "password"
            dhcp4: true
```

sudo lshw -C network

```
  *-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: 82577LM Gigabit Network Connection
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 19
       bus info: pci@0000:00:19.0
       logical name: enp0s25
       version: 05
       serial: 68:b5:99:f9:b9:87
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=3.2.6-k firmware=0.12-3 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:29 memory:d7400000-d741ffff memory:d742a000-d742afff ioport:6020(size=32)
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Centrino Advanced-N 6200
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:44:00.0
       logical name: wlo1
       version: 35
       serial: 58:94:6b:b1:46:f0
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.4.0-31-generic firmware=9.221.4.1 build 25532 ip=192.168.1.24 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:33 memory:d3200000-d3201fff
```

ping -c 5 8.8.8.8

```
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=53 time=53.9 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=2 ttl=53 time=51.9 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=3 ttl=53 time=54.5 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=4 ttl=53 time=52.9 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=5 ttl=53 time=54.8 ms

--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
5 packets transmitted, 5 received, 0% packet loss, time 4007ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 51.944/53.608/54.825/1.057 ms
```

host www.ebay.com

```
www.ebay.com is an alias for slot9428.ebay.com.edgekey.net.
slot9428.ebay.com.edgekey.net is an alias for e9428.b.akamaiedge.net.
e9428.b.akamaiedge.net has address 23.34.85.161
```

cat /etc/network/interfaces

```
auto wlo1
iface wlo1 inet dhcp
wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf

network={
        ssid="SSIDName"
        psk="password"
        scan_ssid=1

}
```

Comment: link=no suggests a cabling problem. Are you using cat 5e or cat 6 cables? Please describe your cabling from the computer port all the way to the router/modem.

Comment: Are you asking how the server is connected to the network, it is through wifi. To solve the problem sometimes, I have to restart the router. Sometimes it comes online by itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using both NetworkManager and networkd configurations at the same time.

Try this:

Set your `/etc/network/interfaces` to this...

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

Set your `/etc/netplan/*.yaml` to this... keep the spacing, indentation, and no tabs, exactly the same...

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp0s25:
      dhcp4: true
      optional: true
  wifis:
    wlo1:
      dhcp4: true
      access-points:
        "SSIDName":
          password: "password"
          band: 2.4GHz
          channel: 6
```

Then do...

`sudo netplan --debug generate`

`sudo netplan apply`

`reboot`

Comment: I got this: abdullah@home-server:~$ sudo netplan --debug generate
DEBUG:command generate: running ['/lib/netplan/generate']
** (generate:76496): DEBUG: 18:32:45.375: Processing input file /etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml..
** (generate:76496): DEBUG: 18:32:45.375: starting new processing pass
(generate:76496): GLib-GIO-DEBUG: 18:32:45.376: _g_io_module_get_default: Found default implementation local (GLocalVfs) for ?gio-vfs?
/etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml:12:7: Error in network definition: unknown key 'band'
      band: 5GHz
      ^
abdullah@home-server:~$

Comment: I changed the band and channel, still getting the same error. Even with 2.4GHz and channel 6, still the same error. when I remove the band line the error appears at the channel line.

Comment: @Abdullah **Ah! I figured it out!** See the latest edit for my .yaml file. Report back.

Comment: I think now it accepted the configuration, I have applied the same, and rebooted. I will test for couple of days and revert. Thank you

Comment: still facing same problem. Maybe I should mentioned that one way to bring it online either reboot the router or the system itself.

Comment: Another way to bring it back is to disable the WAN setting in the router then reenable, without rebooting any system.

Comment: @Abdullah Have you power-cycled BOTH the router and the DSL/cable modem? Unplug them from AC power. Wait 15 seconds. Plug in the modem. Wait 15 seconds. Plug in the router. Wait 15 seconds. Reboot the computer and retest. Are you using DSL or cable modem? You're using BOTH of my files, correct?

Comment: @Abdullah Install `iputils-tracepath` and edit your question with the output of `tracepath www.ebay.com`.

Comment: @Abdullah Are you able to connect an ethernet cable from the computer to the router and retest?

Comment: It have been more than 2 days working without disconnect. I am marking this answer as accepted. Thank you.

Comment: Just to leave a note that, it seems the problem from the router configuration itself. I have another device (Raspberry) and it also goes time the same time. Thank you @heynnema for the support.

Comment: @Abdullah  re: *"(Raspberry) and it also goes time the same time"* I don't quite understand what you mean. Does the Raspberry have the same problem? If so, reset the router to factory, set it up again, and see if the problem goes away.

Comment: @Abdullah Do `iwlist wlo1 freq` and make sure that the channels set in the router, match with one of the available channels in the modem.

Comment: Just to update, there is no issue with the remote system ( I cleaned install both Ubuntu and Raspberry) Still got the same problem. Then I just tried to disconnect and connect my device from the network, and it works again. Maybe something I have to do in my system (MacOS).

Comment: I found out that when Ubuntu (server) and my Mac (client) on the same band 5GHz, the problem occurs. I put the Ubuntu on 2.4GHz and kept the Max on 5GHz, it is working fine.

Comment: @Abdullah Thanks for the update!